# How to fix broken scroll-to ID on main menu of homepage?

Tags: jquery, wordpress, menu, jquery-animate, scrollto

I've taken over the task to maintain a website. Unfortunately the previous maintainer installed quite a lot of WordPress plugins so it's hard for me to figure out which plugin is actually used for what.

I have to figure out, why in our main menu the scroll-to-links are broken but I don't even know where to start. The HTML looks correct:

```
<a href="#orchester-neu">Orchester</a>
```

Whereas the link https://www.akkordeonorchester-muenchen.de/#orchester-neu works perfectly fine.

So I looked in the Google Chrome Console which throws Violation Warnings like

> [Violation] 'requestAnimationFrame' handler took 107ms

As far as I know, "scroll-to" is done by jQuery "animate" function, so this might be a hint on where to start fixing the problem. But the website uses a child-theme of Simple Key Theme and as far as I know, there is no custom code so far. I don't mind adding custom code but as I said, I don't know where to start looking for the error.

Even though it is a WordPress website, I don't think the issue is related to WordPress but to some *JavaScript* / *jQuery* -Script.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this jQuery Code and It'll works fine...

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    jQuery( "#primary-menu-container .menu-item a[href^='#']").on( 'click', function ( e ) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var hash = this.hash;
        var scrlTopOff = jQuery('#primary-menu').innerHeight();
        jQuery( 'html, body' ).animate( {
            scrollTop: jQuery( hash ).offset().top - scrlTopOff
        }, 700, function () {
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: Thanks Asfan! Can you explain to me, why it doesn't work without your function? It used to work, so something must have been broken?

Comment: I have noticed that there is a button to scroll back to the top and It's also doesn't work while clicking on it. So, I think there might be other scrolling functionalities doesn't work. You have missed some custom `js` file/files to include in your template.

Comment: Ok and how do I find the missing files? Or find the broken functionalities?

Comment: You have to compare your included files in your template with original theme files using `view source`.